# Logic App starting with a recurrence trigger not getting triggered without the "Run Trigger" action manually

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[image: Recurrence Trigger][image: Logic App Flow]I have a Logic App where the flow gets triggered by a recurrence trigger which is scheduled to run at 3am on Thursday.
The action is to read an email with a specific Subject line and save its attachment to an Azure blob.
The recurrence trigger works when triggered manually but doesn't run otherwise.
This is part of an automation pipeline and I created this workflow so that the files which gets stored in Azure blob can be used in an Analytics workflow.
Do I need to create an Event Grid trigger to again trigger the recurrence trigger in Logic Apps?
Where exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to share your flow and some screenshots man, near on impossible to help without it.

Comment: My bad, edited with the Logic App flow and Recurrence trigger pictures.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you haven't set the `Recurrence` trigger with appropriate settings. Make sure you set the properties as below to make the flow trigger on every Thursday at 3am.

[image]

Below is the codeview of my Logic App

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {},
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Week",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "schedule": {
                        "hours": [
                            "3"
                        ],
                        "minutes": [
                            0
                        ],
                        "weekDays": [
                            "Thursday"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "type": "recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```