# Logic App with a recurrence schedule not getting triggered without the "Run Trigger" action manually

Tags: azure, http, triggers, azure-logic-apps, recurrence

I have a Logic App set with the following recurrence:

[image]

Each parallel action makes an http call to an api.
For some reason, the calls are not being triggered at the schedule set in Recurrence..

It only works if I run the logic app manually hitting "Run Trigger".

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the trigger and putting it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @ Skin , try once deleting and recreating logic app and check if it works.

There might be some of reasons where logic app trigger failed to run on schedule. One of the reasons is not configuring timings properly.

- Check in your logic app, you have added parameters properly or not as highlighted in below screen shot.
  [image]
- Sometimes errors in logic app also might be reason for not triggering logic app. So check in in your trigger history whether there are any errors that is preventing logic app to trigger. This can be viewed in overview tab under trigger history,
  [image]
- If there are any virtual network is configured in your logic app check if they are connected properly.
- If any of the above mentioned reasons did not work for you, i will suggest you to create a request with Microsoft support.

Also refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74375301/logic-app-starting-with-a-recurrence-trigger-not-getting-triggered-without-the) thread it may helps.

Comment: Well, deleting and re-creating worked. Classic